# Centos 7 apache cannot bind port 80

Tags: apache-2.4, bind, port, centos7

I've a freshly installed Centos 7 with just the basics and apache-php-mysql but I cannot find a way to run apache on port 80.

Since the machine is used just locally I've disabled selinux and firewall, when I try to run apache I get:

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:80 
no listening sockets available, shutting down 
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I've already checked on port 80 with `netstat -tlnp`
 but there is nothing running

Comment: is your loopback interface up? can you ping 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with SELinux (which you should not have disabled).

You cannot start Apache as a regular user and bind to port 80. You must start it as root, and you should use the included systemd unit to do so.

```
sudo systemctl start httpd
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the message states that there is a Permission error. Make sure that the Apache has the correct filesystem access.

I also just found this which may help.

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied

Comment: The rest of the line indicates that the permission denied is the permission to create a listening socket. It's not a filesystem access error.

Comment: I did see that, it looks like I misread the error codes (oops!)